# What data formats that can be published on the first level (1 star) of open data?

Tags: data-format, 5-star-scheme

I wonder what are the possible data formats that can be published for 1-star [level of open data](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html).

The only example I have found is with the PDF format, I wonder if there are other possible formats to obtain the first star.

Comment: what about the possible data formats for publishing in other levels?

Comment: Maria, feel free to [ask another question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 4):

For level 1, any format is fine. Even a picture of data written on a sheet of paper is OK. That's because level 1 is only about web availability and license.

So, yes, any format: PDF, XLS, CSV, JPG, SQL, or even opaque binary blobs.

From http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html :

> (1 star) Available on the web (whatever format) but with an open licence, to be Open Data

[image: Open data stars mug]